# Is ALAsset customMetadata property missing from iOS 5?

Tags: ios, ios5, alasset

The official Apple documentation available online at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html

documents the availability of a customMetadata property for ALAsset instances, but trying to access this property in my app running on an iOS 5.0.1 device (or an iOS 5 simulator instance) results in an unrecognized selector error. The app is compiled with the latest version of Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard and is otherwise able to access other ALAsset properties that are new in iOS 5 (for example, isEditable).

Am I missing something obvious or is the documentation inconsistent with the actual SDK?

Thanks,

Berend

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I was wondering the exact same thing...

Comment: No, not so far. I am pretty sure this is an inconsistency in the Apple documentation. They also claimed that starting with iOS 5 apps were going to have the ability to delete items from the asset library (provided they added them in the first place), but no such call exists in the SDK. I've tried calling writeModifiedImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum with various things that could indicate that I'd like the item to be  replaced with "nothing," but none of those approaches worked...

Comment: just a thought, did the property `editable` work for you and did it return `YES`?